# Export multiple classes in ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, module, export, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm trying to create a module that exports multiple ES6 classes. Let's say I have the following directory structure:

```
my/
└── module/
    ├── Foo.js
    ├── Bar.js
    └── index.js
```

`Foo.js` and `Bar.js` each export a default ES6 class:

```
// Foo.js
export default class Foo {
  // class definition
}

// Bar.js
export default class Bar {
  // class definition
}
```

I currently have my `index.js` set up like this:

```
import Foo from './Foo';
import Bar from './Bar';

export default {
  Foo,
  Bar,
}
```

However, I am unable to import. I want to be able to do this, but the classes aren't found:

```
import {Foo, Bar} from 'my/module';
```

What is the correct way to export multiple classes in an ES6 module?

Comment: just use `export` without the default

Comment: You can only have one `default` export. Imagine if someone tried to do `import SomeClass from 'my/module'`. This would automatically import the `default` module from that path. If you had multiple default exports there, how would it know which one to import?

Answer (score 378, accepted):

Try this in your code:

```
import Foo from './Foo';
import Bar from './Bar';

// without default
export {
  Foo,
  Bar,
}
```

Btw, you can also do it this way:

```
// bundle.js
export { default as Foo } from './Foo'
export { default as Bar } from './Bar'
export { default } from './Baz'

// and import somewhere..
import Baz, { Foo, Bar } from './bundle'
```

Using `export`

```
export const MyFunction = () => {}
export const MyFunction2 = () => {}

const Var = 1;
const Var2 = 2;

export {
   Var,
   Var2,
}


// Then import it this way
import {
  MyFunction,
  MyFunction2,
  Var,
  Var2,
} from './foo-bar-baz';
```

The difference with `export default` is that you can export something, and apply the name where you import it:

```
// export default
export default class UserClass {
  constructor() {}
};

// import it
import User from './user'
```

Comment: I am getting an `Unexpected token` error when building `export Foo from './Foo'; export Bar from './Bar'`

Comment: @inostia note, this is ES6 syntax, you probably need "babel" to support it

Comment: I am using babel. I got that error when compiling with webpack. I think I need to do something like `export { default as Foo } from './Foo';`. I've seen that elsewhere

Comment: @inostia I also am experiencing this, `export { default as Foo } from './Foo';` was required to actually export it.

Answer (score 26):

Hope this helps:

```
// Export (file name: my-functions.js)
export const MyFunction1 = () => {}
export const MyFunction2 = () => {}
export const MyFunction3 = () => {}

// if using `eslint` (airbnb) then you will see warning, so do this:
const MyFunction1 = () => {}
const MyFunction2 = () => {}
const MyFunction3 = () => {}

export {MyFunction1, MyFunction2, MyFunction3};

// Import
import * as myFns from "./my-functions";

myFns.MyFunction1();
myFns.MyFunction2();
myFns.MyFunction3();


// OR Import it as Destructured
import { MyFunction1, MyFunction2, MyFunction3 } from "./my-functions";

// AND you can use it like below with brackets (Parentheses) if it's a function 
// AND without brackets if it's not function (eg. variables, Objects or Arrays)  
MyFunction1();
MyFunction2();
```

Answer (score 9):

@webdeb's answer didn't work for me, I hit an `unexpected token` error when compiling ES6 with Babel, doing named default exports.

This worked for me, however:

```
// Foo.js
export default Foo
...

// bundle.js
export { default as Foo } from './Foo'
export { default as Bar } from './Bar'
...

// and import somewhere..
import { Foo, Bar } from './bundle'
```

Answer (score 5):

```
// export in index.js
export { default as Foo } from './Foo';
export { default as Bar } from './Bar';

// then import both
import { Foo, Bar } from 'my/module';
```

Answer (score 5):

For multiple **`classes`** in the same `js` file, extending `Component` from `@wordpress/element`, you can do that :

```js
// classes.js
import { Component } from '@wordpress/element';

const Class1 = class extends Component {
}

const Class2 = class extends Component {
}

export { Class1, Class2 }
```

And import them in another `js` file :

```
import { Class1, Class2 } from './classes';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do.
export{className, className and so on}

Answer (score -5):

For exporting the instances of the classes you can use this syntax:

```
// export index.js
const Foo = require('./my/module/foo');
const Bar = require('./my/module/bar');

module.exports = {
    Foo : new Foo(),
    Bar : new Bar()
};

// import and run method
const {Foo,Bar} = require('module_name');
Foo.test();
```

Comment: this ist not ES6 Syntax