# Should Prototype Be Used In API In The Days Of Modules

Tags: javascript, api, module, ecmascript-6, prototype

I am building a set of utilities for my 'own use' app. Using ES2015, I wonder where I should create the utility functions as independent of each other within the module, ala =>

```
export const doSomething = () => {
 ... }

export const doSomethingElse = () => {
 ... }
```

My question is, is there any need for going the old fashioned way of creating a main object & then extending that object with all the utility functions? Ala =>

```
export const mainObj = function(){
 ... }

mainObj.prototype.doSomething = function(){
 ... }

mainObj.prototype.doSomethingElse = function(){
 ... }
```

Many thanks

Comment: Why add them to the prototype? Why not just make them properties of the main object? `mainObj.method`

Comment: That would be fine as well. The question is, should one prefer one pattern to another given all the rest of the variables being equal?

Comment: Would [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340500/export-multiple-classes-in-es6-modules) help?

Comment: I do not think it has anything to do with my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you export functions individually then a bundler / build tool can use tree shaking. That is excluding unused functions from the final script and thereby reducing the code size.

That's not possible (or at least difficult) when you export an object, because properties can be referenced dynamically. So a tool cannot say for sure if a function will be used or not.

If you prefer having an object you can always `import *` which has a similar effect, but prevents tree shaking.

Comment: Thats a wonderful point. And as I am using Webpack, it makes sense. I wanted to find out if there are any benefits to still going the old way, I guess, there aren't.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a few ways. Manipulating prototypes is definitely not the clean way to go. You probably just want plain objects OR classes.

This is how I usually structure modules that expose free functions:

```
// Either 
const foo = function foo (...args) {
  return args;
};

module.exports = {
  foo
  // …
};

// Or if you do not need to reference other functions in 
// the same module
module.exports = {
  foo (...args) {
    return args;
  }
  // …
};
```

Comment: Why classes? Just curious...

Comment: Well, since ES6 has classes now, it also has a standard way to handle prototypes and prototypical inheritance. This is a big step forward for ES and if possible should be embraced.

Comment: You know ES6 classes is just syntax sugar for prototypal inheritance, right?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly my point.

Comment: Ok, but I do recommend you [read this piece](https://github.com/joshburgess/not-awesome-es6-classes).

Comment: Thanks. I don't personally use classes at all. I completely avoid them for various reasons. I do think however that one way to work with prototypes that is the same over a platoon of libraries is better than n ways for m libraries.