# How to add imports to default export in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have this TypeScript node module that imports some base errors (`errors1` and `errors2`) and define some module specific `errors3`:

```
// in errors3.ts
import errors1 from './errors1'
import errors2 from './errors2'

const errors3 = {
  ...
}

export default ? // <-- want to merge and export all errors here
```

Is there a way to combine all 3 error objects into one default export without explicit merging these objects into one manually (i.e. via `Object.assign`, `lodash`, etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a barrel to export them all and then import them under a namespace.

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/barrel.html

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I am aware of this rollup technique that requires creating another file. I am wondering if there is a way to stay with the 3 files shown in the description. Maybe this can be solved at the syntax level. Not sure.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe export {errors1, errors2, errors3} as allErrors?

Comment: I think this is what you want. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340500/export-multiple-classes-in-es6-modules

Comment: Doesn't look like I'd be able to do `import errors from './errors3'` and get all errors in one object. Maybe what I'm asking for doesn't exist and the only way to do what I need is to export it via `export default Object.assign(errors3, errrors2, errors1)`