# Why doesn't IntelliSense automatically import my class if its instance is exported as the default?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

Many times, I create a class in a file and export its instance. However, there is an issue with the IntelliSense not working (Ctrl + Space) and being unable to find the import for auto-import using Enter key while this works perfectly if I export the class itself. How can I resolve this problem? I have attempted this in both ReactJS and a pure JavaScript + Webpack project, and both encounter the same problem. Please note that I do not wish to use TypeScript.

```
class ServiceManager {
  constructor() {
    this.value = 'Hello, World!';
  }

  getValue() {
    return this.value;
  }
}

const myInstance = new ServiceManager();

export default myInstance;
```

Basiclly how can I make it so if I'm about to type "ServiceManager" it can find what I want and auto imports it, as you can see from the following image this does not happen.
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're _expecting_ it to autocomplete but note you can name the default import whatever you like where you import it, what it's named (if anything) in the file it's exported from is irrelevant. I'd guess there's a special case where the file and the object have the same name.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I guess I failed to convey the problem in my question, when you usually code for example JavaScript in vs code, if you have a class in a file that is exported and the class is called "ServiceManager", you simply need to write "Serv" and the auto complete finds it and if you press enter it will automatically import it, this does not happen if a instance is exported instead of class.

Comment: One key difference is the class's name is one of its properties (as with a function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name#class), it's part of the value. Not so the instance.

Comment: you exported the instance but you didn't export the class. Why do you expect to even be able to import the class from somewhere else if you didn't export it from there?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/54378476/11107541

Comment: I found a solution, it seems as long as I export default the "new Class" instead of the instance variable, the intellisense can figure out its path and auto imports it.