# Multiple Exports From React Component Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to create a component library with multiple independent components. The end goal is to allow a user to do something like

```
import One from 'component-library' 
import Two from 'component-library'
<One/>
<Two/>
```

But I haven't been able to get anything to work.

My current layout is

```
src
 -index.tsx
 -components
  -one
  -two
```

An example of what my code looks like:

One.tsx

```
export default class One {
 ...
}
```

and then in my root index.tsx

```
import {default as One} from './components/one/One.tsx'
import {default as Two} from './components/two/Two.tsx'

export {
  one,
  two
}
```

This however doesn't work and returns undefined when attempting to import as demonstrated above. I was however able to get this to work only using one component and `export {default} from './components/one/One.tsx'` or just doing `import One from '.components/one/One.Tsx'` so I think my build process should be fine. In that case the component displayed correctly in my other project.

I've also tried modifying my structure and how I'm importing, for example using an index.tsx file in each of the components and exporting/importing from there. All of these have netted the same, returning undefined.

How can I export these correctly so that each one is discretely importable in a 3rd party project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export multiple classes in ES6 modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340500/export-multiple-classes-in-es6-modules)

Comment: I've tried the solution proposed here and It nets the same result as mentioned above.

Comment: What you have there only vaguely looks like the answer to the duplicate question. Also, JavaScript variables are case-sensitive -- `one != One`, etc

Answer (score 5):

Like Highlander, there can be only *one* default export from a given module.  You can get the imports you want by importing distinct modules:

```
import One from 'component-library/One';
import Two from 'component-library/Two';
```

Or, you can use named exports and imports:

```
import { One, Two } from 'component-library';
```

But you can't have the same import return two different things based on the import name.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code:

```
import one from './components/one/One.tsx';
import two from './components/two/Two.tsx';

export const One = one;
export const Two = two;
```

Then you can use it like below:

```
import {One, Two} from 'component-library';

<One/>
<Two/>
```

Comment: The code is unworkable. There's syntax mistake with export.

Comment: Try this: export const One; instead of export One; Similar changes required for Two.

Comment: This won't work. Please, try it yourself before posting, that's how it can be guaranteed that it will work for other users and receive positive votes.

Comment: Hi, Please check  link https://repl.it/@bankim2402/Multiple-Exports-From-React-Component-Library for working example. Let me know if this will not work for you.