# Export as default multiple imported modules

Tags: javascript

How do I export as default multiple imported modules?

I could do something like the code below, but if I were to import multiple files the boilerplate could grow quickly. Is there a shorthand way to achieve this?

```
import Foo from './Foo'
import Bar from './Bar'
//...

export default {
    Foo,
    Bar
    //...
}
```

Note that in my code above, I'm not exporting multiple values. I'm importing multiple values, accumulating them, and exporting them as a single object. I intend to refer to the reexported values by `Baz.Foo` or `Baz.Bar`, assuming the code above is `Baz.js`.

Comment: Read this page:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340500/export-multiple-classes-in-es6-modules

Comment: Finally found a shorthand way that works with default exports. I'm using it in my application now :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of accumulating boilerplate from importing lots of files to simply re-export them, you can do this:

```
// In library.js
export { default as Foo } from "./Foo.js";
export { default as Bar } from "./Bar.js";

// In new_file.js
import { Foo, Bar } from "../lib/library.js"
var phooey = new Foo();
```

This selects whatever you are exporting as default and gives it an alias.

Comment: This is how I intend to use the reexported modules. However, in `library.js`, the import/export code still have to be repeated twice. My question is whether there's an easier way to do that, e.g. `export default {Foo from './Foo', 'Bar' from './Bar'}`

Comment: I updated my answer. Sorry I misunderstood initially! Import/export code isn’t repeated twice in my new example.

Answer (score 1):

`export default` is not meant to be used with multiple exports: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Using_the_default_export

> If we want to export a single value or to have a fallback value for your module, you could use a default export

You should use named exports like this:

```
export {
    Foo,
    Bar
    //...
}
```

Comment: In my code above, I'm not exporting multiple values. I'm importing multiple values, accumulating them, and exporting them as a single object. What I intended was to refer to the reexported values by `Baz.Foo` or `Baz.Bar`, assuming the code above is `Baz.js`

Comment: Then group your imports in an object and export that object as default.

Comment: that's what I did. I just didn't give that object an identifier. E.g. `const toBeExported={Foo, Bar}; export default toBeExported`

Answer (score 1):

In es6 there are two types of exports named and default exports.

Since you want to export default assign all the modules to an object like below

```
Const modules = {Foo,  Bar }
export default modules;
```

Then in other files use like below

```
Import modules from 'path/yourfiles'
modules.Foo.xxx
modules.Bar.xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as name from "module-name";
```

This will be a great fit for your application.
And when you want to access the object, you can use

```
name.object = ...;
```

And let me know, if it is right.