# React - exporting multiple classes in the same file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a project in react where I have multiple components. I am trying to do it all in JSBin (lol.. I know). But i am having issues with exporting multiple classes.

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {

        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div></div>
        );
    }
}


class Bar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {

        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div></div>
        );
    }
}

export class Foo{};
export class Bar{};
```

But I am getting an error of

```
  Parsing error: Identifier 'Foo' has already been declared
  92 | }
  93 | 
> 94 | export class Foo{};
     |              ^
  95 | export class Bar{};
```

So then I tried to change it to this

```
class Foo extends React.Component {...my code}
class Bar extends React.Component {...my code}
```

and it compiles but I get an runtime error of

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function       (for composite components) but got: object.
```

Is it possible to export multiple classes in a single file with react?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340500/export-multiple-classes-in-es6-modules
go through the link , its similar to your issue

Comment: ^^ I tried those solutions but I think my error stems from my classes extending React.Component and both having constructors with call to super() ?

Comment: @eskimo_amigo please share your jsbin project

Comment: did you try just exporting `export class Foo extends React.Component` and remove those two line where you redeclare a class Foo ? `export class Foo{};`

Answer (score 3):

It's because you are re-declaring the class at the bottom, you can export your classes like the following.

```
export class Foo extends React.Component {
   // your code
}

export class Bar extends React.Component {
  // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your classes as usual, then export all your classes at the end of the file as the following

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return <div></div>;
  }
}

class Bar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return <div></div>;
  }
}

export { Foo, Bar };
```

Or if you prefer, you can export the class as you declare them.

```
export class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return <div></div>;
  }
}

export class Bar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return <div></div>;
  }
}
```

Generally its suggested that only export one component per file as per [es-lint's rule](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-multi-comp.md).

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
export Foo;

export Bar;
```

in the end instead of declaring the class again.